# Prove E(A|G) = $1/2(1_A(\omega) + 1_A(-\omega))$, where G = $\sigma(x)$ for $x = \omega^2$

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation

I am extremely stuck on this problem, no idea how to even get started. Any help appreciated.

Let $(\Omega, F, P) = ([0, 1], B([0, 1]), \operatorname{Leb}/2)$, where Leb refers to the Lebesgue measure. Show that for the random variable $X(\omega) = \omega^2$, and $\mathcal G = \sigma(X)$, that for $A \in \mathcal F$...

$\mathbb E(A|\mathcal G) = E(1_A|\mathcal G) = \frac{1}{2}(1_A(\omega) + 1_A(-\omega))$.

EDIT: Image of the question.
[image: ques]

Comment: I cannot parse $E(A|G)$ for $A$ a Borel set and $G$ the std-deviation of the square of a random variable. And $1_A(\omega)$ means $\mu_\omega(1_A)$ with $\mu_\omega$ the probability measure of $\omega$ ?

Comment: Sorry, this is the expectation of whether or not A occurs given the information in G. So we know the information contained in G, and we are trying to see E(A|G). $1_A$ represents an indicator variable.

I'm having trouble parsing it too, part of why I need help :/

Comment: I meant if $1_A(\omega)$ means $\mu_\omega(A) = \int_\Omega 1_A d\mu_\omega$ or not

Comment: No no, it's just an indicator I think. I posted a link to the full problem in the post. I think I wrote out everything relevant but maybe you can see something important I left out.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot replace the interval $[-1,1]$ in the original question to $[0,1]$. (If $A \in \mathcal F$ then $A$ is a subset of $[0,1]$ so $I_A(-\omega)=0$ for all $\omega \in [0,1]$). If this question has to make sense you have change the interval to $[-1,1]$.

Hints for solution. We can describe $\mathcal G$ as $\{B\cup -B:B \, \text {is Borel in} [0,1]$. Once you prove that you can easily verify the identity $E(A|\mathcal G)=\frac 1 2 (I_A+I_{-A})$ by applying the definition of definition of conditional expectation and using the property $ Leb (-C) =Leb (C)$ for any Borel set $C$. 
To show that $\mathcal G$ has above form note  first that $\mathcal G=\{X^{-1}(B): B \,\text {Borel}\}$. Then note that $B\cup -B=X^{-1}(B)$ for any Borel set $B$ in $[0,1]$. Hence sets of the form $B\cup -B=X^{-1}(B)$ belong to $\mathcal G$. The converse is very easy and I leave that to you.